# Copy Row Values to all Rows of one Column

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

My project requires a similar approach of this example: https://codecentral.devexpress.com/E2026/

Is it possible to do it without the popup and reflect the changed values on the database? And just noticed that it wasn't done using batch mode. Is this possible also on the batch mode and sqldatasource? Hope someone here can help me with this. Or any sample, idea and suggestion will do. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an older approach. Consider using the Batch Edit Mode (i.e., without a popup) instead and save data to the required storage.
Check out the following examples to see possible solutions:

[(In-Memory) Batch Edit via List of Objects](https://www.devexpress.com/example=E5045)

[(DB) Batch Edit via EntityDataSource (change it to SqlDataSource with specified CRUD commands)](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/BatchEditing.aspx)

Comment: I'm actually using Batch Edit Mode. But I need the part where the user is able to changed all the item in the column cell at one time.

Comment: I mean if the first value on the column changed all the value on that column will changed. Just like on the sample that I link.